# Custom lstlisting highlighting for symbols

Tags: listings, source

I using the Listings package to pretty print CUDA source code listings.

CUDA is a dialect of C++, so I define my style as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\lstfont}[1]{\color{#1}\scriptsize\ttfamily}

\lstset{
    language=[ANSI]C++,
    showstringspaces=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!90},
    basicstyle=\lstfont{white},
    identifierstyle=\lstfont{white},
    keywordstyle=\lstfont{magenta!40},
    numberstyle=\lstfont{white},
    stringstyle=\lstfont{cyan},
    commentstyle=\lstfont{yellow!30},
    emph={
        cudaMalloc, cudaFree,
        __global__, __shared__, __device__, __host__,
        __syncthreads,
    },
    emphstyle={\lstfont{green!60!white}},
    breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
__global__
void foo()
{}

foo<<<n,m>>>();
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This produces great results, with the CUDA-specific keywords that I want to emphasize printed in green.

[image]

(note that there is a typo in the screen shot, which is missing an additional closing `>`)

This works very well for keywords, but I want to extend it to also render the `<<<` and `>>>` symbols in the following code snippet green:

```
kernel<<<n, m>>>();
```

Is there a way to get Listings to render specific sequences of symbols in a chosen style, similarly to how it can be done using `emph` for keywords?

Comment: [listings documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), section 3.3 "Delimiters", specifically the `moredelim` option. Something like `moredelim=[s][\ttfamily]{<<<}{>>>}` would put the symbols and contents in a typewriter font. Further suggestions would be easiest with a complete MWE (you have color references in your code I wasn't able to replicate easily).

Comment: Hi Mike, I have updated the question with a minimal example. Sorry for being so sloppy in my original submission.

Comment: Do you want the `n,m` in green as well, or in white?

Comment: just the ```<<<``` and ```>>>```. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeRenfro Do you want to write up an answer?